# Animate an object in 3D given by six lines

Tags: graphics3d

I have a structure defined by six line segments connecting six points.  The coordinates of the six points change with time.  Each coordinate has a formula giving it as a function of time.  Three of them are constant.

How do I animate this?  How do I control timing, color, width of lines, and the observer's point of view?

Example: One of the six points looks like

```
(4/3, (-2*r2*tg^2+2*r2) / (3*tg^2 + 3), (4*r2*tg) / (3*tg^2 + 3) )
```

where `r2 = sqrt(2)`, `tb` runs through values between `[-.7, .7]` and `tg` is a function of `tb` given by a formula involving a square root.  Some of the other points are more complicated, but this is the flavor.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: It is not possible to provide advice with so little information.  Please provide your Mathematica code defining the line segments, along with other relevant code you may have.

Comment: `GraphicsComplex[]` should be useful. You can put the varying coordinates in the first argument, and use indices to those points in the primitives in the second argument.

Comment: You are not even using valid *Mathematica* syntax -- how do you expect to solve this problem ?

Comment: I think you should start with figuring out how to animate one point in 2D in Mathematica. When you are successful with that it will be relatively easy to generalize it for your case. The point `(4/3, (-2*r2*tg^2+2*r2) / (3*tg^2 + 3), (4*r2*tg) / (3*tg^2 + 3) )` moves in YZ plane, so visualize this in 2D first.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about your definition of structure... In 2D you can get something like this. You need it in 3D?

```
hexPoints = Table[{Cos[2 Pi i/6], Sin[2 Pi i/6]}, {i, 0, 5}];
motion[t_] := {0.2 {Cos[8 t], Sin[5 t]}, {0.5 t, 0}, {0.1 t, 0.3 t}}~
   Join~Table[{0, 0}, {i, 1, 3}];
points[t_] := hexPoints + motion[t];
hexSegments[t_] := 
  Partition[#, 2] &@Riffle[#, RotateLeft[#, 1]] &@points[t];

t = 0;

Animate[Show[
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[points[t]], Blue, 
    Line[hexSegments[t]]}], PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {t, 0, 
  2}]
```

[image]

You have to setup your points and segments of course. You can easily "upgrade it" to 3D.